# number the lines in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I want to know if there's a way to number the lines in TinyMCE like in an text editor

like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TinyMCE has no built in capability to do this in its WYSISYG view.  It does offer a premium plugin called Advanced Code View that will provide line numbers when looking at the HTML code view.